# Which colors were rare for leather to be dyed?

Tags: medieval, materials, colors, unusual-color

My character has a book of research bound in leather. To make the cover of her book distinguishable, she has the leather dyed a rare color. Which color might that be? Assume money is no object. The story takes place in a medieval setting and I know some colors were rarer than others (purple, royal blue) but I'm unsure if they were used for leather specifically.

Edited to add: this is a fantasy world that takes place in a time period similar to the Renaissance. My character lives in a country I've loosely based on the Mediterranean (as a general region, not a specific country) and it borders the sea.

I don't know if this adds or takes away from my question but for those wanting more specificity, that's the larger context.

Comment: The color royal blue was not "rare" in the Middle Ages; it just did not exist at all. It was [invented in the 18th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Royal_blue&oldid=1207348231). And before modern times the word purple meant some sort of deep dark red. It still has this meaning in Romance languages; for example, the original French title of Mathieu Kassovitz's film [*The Crimsom Rivers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crimson_Rivers) (2000) is *Les rivières pourpres*, where the word refers to the color of blood.

Comment: Suggest that this may get a better response on HistorySE.  Both there and here it will get a better reception with a more specific time period ("medieval" is very long) and geographic area.  (British Isles?  China?  Somewhere *specific* between those two locations?)  Note that the presence or absence of long distance trade may be the difference between a colour being expensive vs completely unavailable.

Comment: Purple used to be a very expensive color to produce. This eas because i think it was extracted from a sea snail or something. And you needed lots of them for even a little bit of dye.

Comment: I seem to recall that that some cultures there were laws against possessing blue or purple clothing. Romans? witch would make it rare for a novel reason.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock yes, it was a snail, and the smell of crushed purple dye snails was heinously bad and unbearable. You got milligrams of dye out of each snail, you needed hundreds of them.

Comment: also, I disagree with the close vote. The question IS about worldbuilding.

Comment: Can't see it @Mindwin Remember Monica but it might because this question refers to very strict real world knowledge. But i also disagree with the closing vote. Simultaneously it would help if the author clarified a view things.

Comment: This will be tricky, since most leather does not dye well beyond a relatively small handful of colors, and the varieties that do are relatively recent inventions (such as nubuck and suede) are comparatively recent inventions. Also, exactly _when_ and exactly _where_ matter, a lot. 5th century Greece would have different options than 10th century Scotland, and both would have drastically different options than 15th century China.

Comment: To me this seems more suited to our [history.se] site than here.

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. beware the *"Q is better suited elsewhere"* trap. The choice of which Stack a question is posted tells us what kind of **specialists** the OP wants answers from. I believe OP **doesn't need** historical accurate facts. Only believable ones to put in his story. Therefore, the specialists here on WB.SE are the ones he asked for help. - - - - -  A Q can fit more than one Stack. That's fine. Migrating questions is a big headache most of the time.

Comment: ESPECIALLY when OP is a "new contributor". Remember the principle of charity. Do not migrate questions unless you have **absolute certainty** the question is well-formatted for the other Stack you are **dumping** it to.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica Thanks for your advice, but: 1) "Which colors were rare for leather to be dyed?" - is literally an historical question. Had the body of the question contained sufficient information on *their* world, to decide what might "have been" rare there, then it might have worked here. 2) I did check on our history stack before posting the comment, they have questions relating to various parts of the world and dyes in ancient times.

Comment: Cont.  3) I don't possess the privilege to migrate questions, only mods/staff do. 4) Reminding the OP to take the tour, read the help centre on any site before posting is a very good idea, absolutely.

Comment: 1) I'm not contesting it. 2) neither this. 3) yes, but it requires a close vote 4) sure.

I would like to repeat this: A Q can fit more than one Stack. But an answer in HIstory.se would be too much. For example, the suggestion by Stafish Prime would never appear there. Given the votes, many people here agree it is a good fit to solve the question's issue. e.g. creating a distinctive book cover that instantly tells the reader the book is expensive and important.

Comment: Worse, some sites (like skeptics, stackoverflow) demand a basis in a real-life experience before a question is posted. Purely hypotheticals are frowned upon there.

Answer (score 27):

The classic example might be [Tyrian purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_purple) which is somewhat inconvenient to produce. There were other purple colors, but the best kind was much more robust to things like sunlight which would fade and discolor the cheaper kinds over time. This slightly suggests to me that a purple book in itself is not necessarily unusual unless it is also an *old* purple book.

If you want your book to stand out, and money is no object, merely making it purple might not be enough. You'll be wanting metal, preferably the precious kind. Enter: treasure binding!

[image: A book, bounding in leather, with golden embossed corner pieces and gold crosses inlaid which gemstones]

<sub>([Armenian gospels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:T%27oros_Roslin_-_T%27oros_Roslin_Gospels_-_Walters_W539_-_Closed_Front.jpg), 1262, with metal elements over leather, image credit "Bequest of Mrs. Henry Walters [formerly part of the Walters Collection], 1935" via wikimedia)</sub>

Now *that* is a distinctive book.

Comment: Aluminum bound book.

Comment: @DKNguyen _very_ fancy.

Comment: @DKNguyen Aluminum was not discovered until 1825.  From about 1825-1886, yes, it was more precious than gold, but that does not line up with the medieval time frame.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Which makes it rare to the extreme! Could only be acknowledged as a little wizard's book. It could work if the character is a wizard or alchemist or something of the like. It is a research diary after all. It'd be like finding a book bound in one of the synthetic elements in modern times. Probably as close as you can get to the Silmarils in the real world.

Comment: "Somewhat inconvenient to produce" is really understating it for Tyrian purple!

Answer (score 16):

**The important aspect here is the word "dyed"**

Tanned leather has color, and as anyone who's tried to re-stain a deck with a new color will tell you, that pre-existing color is the problem. Because of that pre-existing color, there is a [set of common colors that are almost always what we see](https://www.beaverbushcraft.co.uk/page_3247239.html).

The further outside that color range (a light tan or "natural" to black, ranging through shades of red to produce browns) the more remarkable and rare the coloring process must be.

From a medieval standpoint, your answer must not only be an uncommon color to obtain, but also a color that would be a sincere pain in the rumpus to stain leather with. This is because the stain must overcome the pre-existing color, likely by absorbing significant quantities of solids into the leather, especially near (and yet below) its surface.

That's the difference between dying and painting. A dye must be absorbed into the surface of the object. A paint merely coats the surface to hide it.

While historically [yellows were available during the medieval period](https://historicenterprises.com/fabrics-colors-c-100_198_200.html), they were often dull or brownish. However...

> Weld is the most common yellow dyestuff, producing a vivid, almost unbelievably electric yellow colour. Unfortunately, it is not a very fast colour and the intensity fades quickly. (*Ibid.*)

So the question is how to protect the vivid "electric yellow" of the stain? From our sister site Skeptics.SE (of all places...) we learn:

> Salt has been used as a mordant (dye-fixer) for ages. Packs of RIT brand dye suggest adding salt (or vinegar, for synthetics) to the dye bath to help the color set.
>
> https://www.ritdye.com/techniques/the-basics/stovetop-technique/
>
> OTOH, they are also using the hottest water possible, which is hard on clothes, so not for frequent use. Note also that this is for when you are dying cloth and may not be any help when washing same. ([Source](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/39119/50168))

**Conclusion**

A vivid, bright (electric) yellow, which can be set in the leather using salt and hot water. A (admittedly very rapid) Google search suggests it would be unique.